# Use Jsoup catch website data cannot display at console

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want catch Table data and display at console
Link:http://www.laliga.es/en/statistics/laliga-santander

code:

```
public class pldata {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.legaseriea.it/en/serie-a-tim/league-table").get();
        Elements Playeds = doc.select("td.blue");
        for(Element Played:Playeds)
        {
            String found = Played.text();
            System.out.println(found);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `doc.select("CLASS NAME GOES HERE")` Class name, **"td.blue"** is not in the link you've provided, to find out the appropriate css selector of an element right click on the element you want, and look at the upper part of the Inspector, it's shown in blue arrow in the picture use that as the selector, hope this helps.

[image]